# Test build step in TFS 2017 does not appear to run

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have been setting up build configurations in TFS 2017.

As part of the build configuration I have Test steps.

When the build runs the test steps seems to run without error.

I committed some code in with a test I set to fail, to make sure that TFS stopped the build in the event tests fail. I queued a new build and then surprisingly the build completed with no issue.

I am having this issue on full framework libraries, that are being packaged into NuGet packages and also having it with .net core projects.

On evaluating the log for the test step I see the following messages.

These are from a .Net Core build

**The build log**
[image]

**The build step for a core project**
[image]

These ones are from a full framework build config

**The build log for full framework**

```
 ##[section]Starting: Test Assemblies **\*test*.dll;-:**\obj\**
 ==============================================================================
 Task         : Visual Studio Test
 Description  : Run tests with Visual Studio test runner
 Version      : 1.0.85
 Author       : Microsoft Corporation
 Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=624539)
 ==============================================================================
 Preparing task execution handler.
 Executing the powershell script: c:\agent\_work\_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\1.0.85\VSTest.ps1
 Testing container: 'REGISTRY::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{177F0C4A-1CD3-4DE7-A32C-71DBBB9FA36D}'

 Exists.

 Adding Visual Studio setup helpers.

 Getting Visual Studio setup instances.

 Found 2 instances.




 Description   : Supports running automated tests and load tests remotely
 DisplayName   : Visual Studio Test Agent 2017
 Id            : 0f053fb9
 InstallDate   : System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME
 Name          : VisualStudio/15.2.0+26430.6
 Path          : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\TestAgent
 Version       : 15.0.26430.6
 VersionString : 15.0.26430.6

 Description   : Microsoft DevOps solution for productivity and coordination 
                 across teams of any size
 DisplayName   : Visual Studio Enterprise 2017
 Id            : e4f83d45
 InstallDate   : System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME
 Name          : VisualStudio/15.4.0+27004.2002
 Path          : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise
 Version       : 15.4.27004.2002
 VersionString : 15.4.27004.2002


 Testing leaf: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\TestAgent\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe'

 Exists.

 Working folder: c:\agent\_work\11\s
 Executing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\TestAgent\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.EDI\*******.EDI.Tests\bin\Release\*******.EDI.Tests.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.EDI\*******.EDI\packages\FluentAssertions.4.19.4\lib\sl5\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTesting.Silverlight.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\cs\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\cs\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\cs\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\es\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\es\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\es\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\fr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\fr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\fr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\it\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\it\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\it\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\ja\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\ja\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\ja\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\ko\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\ko\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\ko\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Interface.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\pl\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\pl\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\pl\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\pt\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\pt\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\pt\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\ru\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\ru\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\ru\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\tr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\tr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\tr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\zh-Hans\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\zh-Hans\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\zh-Hans\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\zh-Hant\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\zh-Hant\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\zh-Hant\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.11\lib\dotnet\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.11\lib\dotnet\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.11\lib\net45\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.11\lib\net45\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.11\lib\netcoreapp1.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.11\lib\netcoreapp1.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.11\lib\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll" "c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.11\lib\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll"  /EnableCodeCoverage /logger:trx /TestAdapterPath:"c:\agent\_work\11\s"
 Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.0.26228.0
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

 Starting test execution, please wait...
 Warning: Using Isolation mode to run the tests as diagnostic data adapters were enabled in the runsettings. Use the /inIsolation parameter to suppress this warning.
 Warning: Unable to load types from the test source 'c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll'. Some or all of the tests in this source may not be discovered.

 Warning: Input string was not in a correct format.

 Warning: Input string was not in a correct format.

 Warning: Input string was not in a correct format.

 Warning: Input string was not in a correct format.

 Warning: Input string was not in a correct format.

 Warning: Unable to load types from the test source 'c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll'. Some or all of the tests in this source may not be discovered.

 Warning: No test is available in c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\zh-Hans\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\zh-Hans\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\zh-Hans\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\tr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\ru\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\tr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\zh-Hant\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\ru\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\ru\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\tr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\zh-Hant\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\pt\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.11\lib\dotnet\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.11\lib\dotnet\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.11\lib\net45\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.11\lib\netcoreapp1.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.11\lib\netcoreapp1.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.11\lib\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.11\lib\uap10.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\zh-Hant\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\pt\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\pl\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\cs\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\cs\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\cs\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\de\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\es\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\es\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\es\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\fr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\fr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\fr\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\pt\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\it\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\it\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\ja\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\ja\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\ja\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\ko\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\ko\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\ko\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Interface.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\pl\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\pl\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\it\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.resources.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.1.1.11\lib\net45\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.EDI\*******.EDI.Tests\bin\Release\*******.EDI.Tests.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.Web\*******.Web\packages\MSTest.TestAdapter.1.1.11\build\_common\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.dll c:\agent\_work\11\s\*******.EDI\*******.EDI\packages\FluentAssertions.4.19.4\lib\sl5\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTesting.Silverlight.dll. Make sure that installed test discoverers & executors, platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.


 Attachments:
   c:\agent\_work\11\s\TestResults\e806ae8a-20fe-40d7-956e-90b827a56c83\Dwainwright_ASSODOPDV01 2017-10-23 15_39_33.coverage

 Information: Additionally, you can try specifying '/UseVsixExtensions' command if the test discoverer & executor is installed on the machine as vsix extensions and your installation supports vsix extensions. Example: vstest.console.exe myTests.dll /UseVsixExtensions:true



 ##[warning]No results found to publish.
 ##[section]Finishing: Test Assemblies **\*test*.dll;-:**\obj\**
```

**The Build Step for full framework**

[image]

---

How can i set up TFS so that the tests are actually ran, and more so, the build stops if any test fails.

Further info:

I have VS 2017 installed on the build server too.

The tests are written in NUnit. Not sure if something else needs adding to the build server. Almost looks as though the build server is trying to use MSTest; i see some references to MSTestAdapter

Comment: Can you run the test as expected in local VS directly?

Comment: Yes. All tests run, for all projects locally; be that Core or full framework.

Answer (score 1):

VSTest task cannot run .NET core tests as it uses the Test platform version 1. To run .NET core tests, we recommend using the .NET core task with the test command.

Reference https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/5066

As a workaroun you can manually invoke `vstest.console.exe` from folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\` and provide `/Framework:FrameworkCore10`.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)>dir vstest.console.exe /s
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is 0835-B24B

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Com
mon7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow

10/24/2017  02:55 PM           137,824 vstest.console.exe
               1 File(s)        137,824 bytes

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Com
mon7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform

09/04/2017  12:09 PM           133,240 vstest.console.exe
               1 File(s)        133,240 bytes
```

Reference https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/579#issuecomment-339263411

---

**UPDATE:**

Make sure you are not missing and dependancies.

Check the packages.config, it should be similar as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="MSTest.TestAdapter" version="1.1.11" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="MSTest.TestFramework" version="1.1.11" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. In the build config for the Core project I am using the dotnet test command. Just not sure if i have it set correctly. The VS Tests shown above are for a full framework project. I just happen to be having the same issue for both types of project.

Comment: @Darren Make sure you are not missing any dependencies. You can check that if all nuget packages restored properly.

Comment: I can confirm everything else is good. The entire package is built and deployed, in all project types. The only thing that doesn't appear to happen is the tests being ran. If i intentionally code a test to fail it appears to 'pass' when being built. I must be missing something super simple, just don't know what

Comment: @Darren Have you tried other projects, do they have the same issue? Try to update your build server agents to the latest version. Also note that you have set the correct patterns for the steps.

Comment: We have 8 or so full framework, class libraries that we package into nuget. 1 core project so far and another solution that builds 3 installable services and a website. All do the same. I updated TFS a week ago.

Comment: @Darren See this similar issue : https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/4654 check if the last reply helps. In addition, if you can run the test successfuly in local VS, then try to copy all the local dependency packages to agent source location, then try it again.